# Opencart 2.2.0 for each category/subcategory display ONLY third level categories in category module

Tags: php, module, opencart, categories

This may be a duplicate, but which ever answer I found, didn't solve my problem.  I have category structure like this: Category->Subcategory->Sub sub category. In my **category module**, I managed to show the whole structure (Category->Subcategory->Subsub category). But what I need is only **Subsub** categories to show for **each** Category or subcategory. My  `category.php` module file looks like this:

```
<?php
class ControllerModuleCategory extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('module/category');

        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);
        } else {
            $parts = array();
        }

        if (isset($parts[0])) {
            $data['category_id'] = $parts[0];
        } else {
            $data['category_id'] = 0;
        }

        if (isset($parts[1])) {
            $data['child_id'] = $parts[1];
        } else {
            $data['child_id'] = 0;
        }

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $data['categories'] = array();

        $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $children_data = array();

            if ($category['category_id'] == $data['category_id']) {
                $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

                foreach($children as $child) {
                    $children_data_2 = array();

                    $children_2 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($child['category_id']);

                    foreach ($children_2 as $child_2) {
    $filter_data = array(
        'filter_category_id'  => $child_2['category_id'],
        'filter_sub_category' => true
    );

    $children_data_2[] = array(
        'category_id' => $child_2['category_id'],
        'name'        => $child_2['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
        'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'] . '_' . $child_2['category_id'])
    );
}

                    $filter_data = array('filter_category_id' => $child['category_id'], 'filter_sub_category' => true);

                    $children_data[] = array(
                        'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
                        'name' => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                        'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id']),
                            'children'    => $children_data_2 // insert this line

                    );
                }
            }

            $filter_data = array(
                'filter_category_id'  => $category['category_id'],
                'filter_sub_category' => true
            );

            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'category_id' => $category['category_id'],
                'name'        => $category['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                'children'    => $children_data,
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
            );
        }

        return $this->load->view('module/category', $data);
    }
}
```

My `category.tpl` module file looks like this:

```
<h3><?php echo "Potkategorije" ?></h3>
<div class="list-group">
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
    <li class="cat-active">
        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
        <b class="cc"></b>
        <ul class="col-subcat">
            <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
            <li>
                <?php if ($child['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($child['children']) { ?>
                <b class="cc"></b>
                <ul class="col-subcat">
                    <?php foreach ($child['children'] as $child_2) { ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php if ($child_2['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $child_2['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $child_2['name']; ?></a>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $child_2['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child_2['name']; ?></a>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
                <?php } ?>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

How to modify files to make this work? I appreciate your time, thanx.

Comment: are you getting whole categories in $categories ?

Comment: Thanx for your reply, Ahmed. Yes, I am getting them all.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx to a good man @Ahmed Ginani, who tried to help me, I relized what was my problem. I never defined current subcategory. Instead, I went on showing the whole structure all at once. So, I had to modify both of my files (php and tpl)  so that only subsubcategories for the current category/subcategory would display. I am  showing the correct files here.

> Category.php:

```
<?php
class ControllerModuleCategory extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('module/category');

        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);
        } else {
            $parts = array();
        }

        if (isset($parts[0])) {
            $data['category_id'] = $parts[0];
        } else {
            $data['category_id'] = 0;
        }

        if (isset($parts[1])) {
            $data['child_id'] = $parts[1];
        } else {
            $data['child_id'] = 0;
        }



        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $data['categories'] = array();

        $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $children_data = array();

            if ($category['category_id'] == $data['category_id']) {
                $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

                foreach($children as $child) {
                    $children_data_2 = array();

                    $children_2 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($child['category_id']);

                    foreach ($children_2 as $child_2) {
    $filter_data = array(
        'filter_category_id'  => $child_2['category_id'],
        'filter_sub_category' =>  true
    );

    $children_data_2[] = array(
        'category_id' => $child_2['category_id'],
        'name'        => $child_2['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
        'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'] . '_' . $child_2['category_id']),

    );
}

                    $filter_data = array('filter_category_id' => $child['category_id'], 'filter_sub_category' => true);

                    $children_data[] = array(
                        'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
                        'name' => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                        'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id']),
                        'children'    => $children_data_2 // insert this line


                    );
                }
            }

            $filter_data = array(
                'filter_category_id'  => $category['category_id'],
                'filter_sub_category' => true
            );

            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'category_id' => $category['category_id'],
                'name'        => $category['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                'children'    => $children_data,
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
            );
        }

        return $this->load->view('module/category', $data);
    }
}
```

> Category.tpl:

```
<div class="list-group">
 <ul id="menu">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : 

        if (!empty($category['children'])) : 
        echo '<h3 style="margin-top:54px;">Potkategorije</h3>';
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach ($category['children'] as $category_level2) :
                if (!empty($category_level2['children']) && $category_level2['category_id'] == $child_id) :
                    echo '<ul>';
                    foreach ($category_level2['children'] as $category_level3) :
                        echo '<li style="list-style-type: none"><a href="'.$category_level3['href'].'">'.$category_level3['name'].'</a></li>';
                    endforeach;
                    echo '</ul>';
                endif;
                echo '</li>';
            endforeach;
            echo '</ul>';
        endif;
        echo '</li>';
    endforeach;
    echo '</ul>';
    ?>
</div>
```

I truly hope this helps someone, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem in variable comparison :

```
<?php foreach ($child['children'] as $child_2) { ?>
<li>
<?php if ($child_2['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
```

To

```
 <?php if ($child_2['category_id'] == $child_2_id) { ?>
```

Comment: I tried, but it hides second and third level and shows first only.

Comment: what is the issue? getting any error or something else

Comment: i think you don't have any child in that category you have to check condition before foreach  if(!empty($child['children'])) {}

Comment: Thanx for your effort, Ahmed, but this doesn't solve my problem.